# How to connect columns in pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I want to connect columns and create another column with name to which set it belongs namely, I have a `dataframe` like this:

```
   x1  x2  x3  x4    y1    y2     y3    y4
1  10  10  10   8  8.04  9.14   7.46  6.58
2   8   8   8   8  6.95  8.14   6.77  5.76
3  13  13  13   8  7.58  8.74  12.74  7.71
```

And want to create one like this:

```
    set  x   y
1   I   10  8.04
2   I   8   6.95
3   I   13  7.58
4   II  10  9.14
5   II  8   8.14
6   II  13  8.74
7   III 10  7.46
...
```

So I want to connect variable `x1` with `y1`, `x2` with `y2` with creation of another column with the label to which set it belongs. I separated this into two dataframes one containing `x1, x2, x3, x4` the other `y1, y2, y3, y4` and then was trying melt function, but I could not get the hang of it.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, don't tell us "could not get the hang of it" -- this leaves your question as an open request for a personal tutorial, or to just do your problem for you -- each of which is off-topic.  Instead, post the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and let us work on *that*.  Given the work to which you refer, it's probably only a line or two change from what you've already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
s=pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['x','y'],i='index',j='set').\
      reset_index(level=1).sort_values('set').reset_index(drop=True)
s
    set   x      y
0     1  10   8.04
1     1   8   6.95
2     1  13   7.58
3     2  10   9.14
4     2   8   8.14
5     2  13   8.74
6     3  10   7.46
7     3   8   6.77
8     3  13  12.74
9     4   8   6.58
10    4   8   5.76
11    4   8   7.71
```

If you like, adjust the `set`:

```
s.set=s.set.map(lambda x : x*'I')
s
     set   x      y
0      I  10   8.04
1      I   8   6.95
2      I  13   7.58
3     II  10   9.14
4     II   8   8.14
5     II  13   8.74
6    III  10   7.46
7    III   8   6.77
8    III  13  12.74
9   IIII   8   6.58
10  IIII   8   5.76
11  IIII   8   7.71
```